# TYPO3 alternative page language configuration

Tags: localization, typo3

I'm trying to join a bunch of pages that are in different languages to a single page whith multiple alternative page languages.

This way, instead of having 3 Home pages, each one with its own language, I have 1 with several alternative page languages. So I'll have one page but the content is in different languages, depending on the language record it uses.

The issue is that TYPO3 extensions should behave differently depending on the language, i.e: form fields should be translated.

For that I was thinking on having a local storage folder for each page language record in order to hold the extension configurations. Chinese language would have a separated storage folder from the english version and the extension running for the chinese version would use the correct storage folder.

But how can I specify which storage folder the extension in the chinese language record should use if I don't use a new page?

Because if I use a language record to differentiate chinese from english I can't have different typoscript configurations. The language record properties page doesn't have a ts config field and as such I can't tell that the extension should use a different storage folder (different pid) for this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each language you can add a cObj plugin and thus edit the plugin configuration. You can also use a condition and getText to assign a new pid to the plugin. For example plugin.test_pi1.sysfolder < 666.

The first option is when you look in the mysql table language overlay you have a separate record ctype plugin of your plugin and thus you can edit the plugin configuration.

Comment: The second option I think I got it...for instance I could change the do the plugin.test_pi1.sysfolder < 666 in the root template like: 
[globalVar = GP:print=1]
plugin.test_pi1.sysfolder < 666
[global]
The first recomendation, the cObj I didn't understand...would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I'm not sure either but you can insert multiple instance of the plugin to each language page overlay and have different configuration?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't got it 100%...do you mean that when I have the plugin in the content page I'll make a "create a copy for translation" like other content element? because I think you don't have that option in plugins ce

Comment: You are absolutely right...you can make translation records of plugins like any other ce (content element). My question is...can you still change, for instance, the storage folder (pid) of the plugin/extension through here? because there is no ts config field in the plugin/extension. that's usually done in the ts config of the template...but I don't want to have a new template for each language

Comment: You can use flexforms to store the storage pid. But I don't know what you mean with ts config field in the extension? You can also look in the page language overlay table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15800/discussion-between-doubter-and-chiyou)